# GitLab rule for runnig job only on setting tag in master/main branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to run some job only on new `tags` in `default` (master/main) branch. Is it possible? Probably like next one:

```
...
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $GIT_COMMIT_TAG
```

But setting tag on some commit isn't an additional commit as I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some job when you tag in master you can use this:

```
only:
    - tags
    - master
```

Comment: As I know it's `OR` logic.